# How to split dataset using JCL based on a specific field?

Tags: jcl

I have a dataset which I need to break into 10 smaller chunks (datasets) based on ID which is unique. The chunks are not supposed to have simillar lenghth. For example ID 1 thru 200 should be in chunk1, ID 201 thru 240 shuld be in chunk2 and etc.
I searched a lot and came accrose the following piece of code that didnt work for me

```
//S1    EXEC  PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT    DD  SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN DD DSN=... input file
//OUT1 DD DSN=...  output file1
//OUT2 DD DSN=...  output file2
//SYSIN    DD    *
  OPTION COPY
  OUTFIL FNAMES=OUT1,INCLUDE=&#40;1,6,PD,LE,200&#41;
FNAMES=OUT2,INCLUDE=&#40;1,6,ch,LE,250&#41
```

Please help me...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the id? Is it in a well-defined location?

Comment: I tried the above code. Id position in my input file is fixed, say position 1 to 6.

Answer (score 2):

Soraya,

Use the following DFSORT JCL which shows how to split the input file into multiple output files.

```
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT                                           
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//SORTIN   DD *                                                    
 01                                                                
 10                                                                
 99                                                                
225                                                                
151                                                                
240                                                                
200                                                                
201                                                                
//OUT1     DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//OUT2     DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//SYSIN    DD *                                                    
  OPTION COPY                                                      
  OUTFIL FNAMES=OUT1,INCLUDE=(1,3,UFF,LE,200)                      
  OUTFIL FNAMES=OUT2,INCLUDE=(1,3,UFF,GT,200,AND,1,3,UFF,LE,240)   
/*
```

The output for OUT1 file will be

```
 01
 10
 99
151
200
```

The output for OUT2 file will be

```
201
225
240
```